# Laravel eloquent manipulate collection

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm running a query which returns a collection array with 7 items -

```
$uniques = Analytics::fetchviews(Period::days(7))->take(7);
```

The collection results look like this-

```
  2 => array:4 [▼
  "date" => Carbon {#247 ▶}
  "uniquePageviews" => 1
  "pageViews" => 1
]
```

I would like to take out the `pageViews` and `uniquePageviews` and work with these integers before passing the results to a view. How can I edit the data within the collection directly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A collection is just a list of models. You can iterate over them, work with their attributes and so forth. For example:

```
foreach ($uniques as $unique) {
   var_dump($unique->pageViews);
}
```

Comment: Do I have to foreach this within the controller I wasn't sure if I could access a object from within the array explicitly. I know this is how you would go about it from within a view.

Comment: Yes, you can foreach in the controller - whether that is the correct place to do so, is another question. If you are doing things like sums, consider querying the database for it in the model. Collections are not actually an array, they just behave similarily. Please refer to [the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections).

Comment: Thanks I would normally manipulate the database data, however this is an api call so I'm a little limited with how I work about doing things.